# Sinon stubs not been called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js

While writing the tests for `baz.View.likeButton`, I come across the issue that when I test to see if a stub has been called on an event I triggered, this stub is never called. This is happening too when I directly call `this.view._update` for example and expect my stubs `likeStub` or `unLikeStub` to be called too. I have checked that the element exits, but do not understand why my expectations are failing.
What am I missing?

My like button view inherits from `BaseButton`, which in turn inherits from `base`.

```
baz.View.likeButton = baz.View.BaseButton.extend({

    template: _.template($('#like-button').html()),
    sPaper: null,
    sPolyFill: null,
    sPolyEmpty: null,
    liked: null,
    likeButn: null,
    model: null,

    events: {
        "click button.icon": "toggleLike"
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        // inherit from BaseButton
        View.BaseButton.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]); // inherit from BaseButtonView

        this.model = options.model;
        this.liked = this.model.get('liked');

        // set initial variables
        this.likeButn = this.$("button.icon", this);

        // pass in el on instantiation
        this.el = options.el;

        this.svgNode = this.likeButn.find("svg").get(0); // find the svg in the likeButn and get its first object
        this.sPaper = Snap(this.svgNode); // pass the svg object into Snap.js
        this.sPolyFill = this.sPaper.select('.symbol-solid');
        this.sPolyEmpty = this.sPaper.select('.symbol-empty');

        this.likeButn.addClass(this.liked ? "liked": "unliked");

        this._update();

        if(this.model)
        {
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change:liked", _.bind(this._modelChange, this))
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        this._update();
        return this;
    },

    toggleLike: function () {
        this.liked = !this.liked;
        this._update();
    },

    _modelChange: function() {
        var bNewState = this.model.get('liked');
        if(bNewState !== this.liked)
        {
            this.liked = bNewState;
            this._update();
        }
    },

    _update: function () {
        if ( this.liked === true ) { // if liked is false, remove class, add class and set isLiked to true, then animate svg to liked position
            this._like();
        } else if ( this.liked === false ) { // is liked is false, remove class, add class, set isLiked to false, then animate svg to unliked position
            this._unlike();
        }
    },

    _like: function() {
        this.likeButn.removeClass("unliked");
        this.likeButn.addClass("liked");
        this.animateLike();
        if(this.model.get('liked') !== true)
        {
            this.model.set('liked', true);
            this.model.set("numLikes", this.model.get("numLikes") + 1);
            // wrapper for API
            likeEntity("/items/"+this.model.id); // should do something better than this to send like to server
        }
    },

    _unlike: function() {
        this.likeButn.removeClass("liked");
        this.likeButn.addClass("unliked");
        this.animateUnlike();
        if(this.model.get('liked') !== false)
        {
            this.model.set('liked', false);
            this.model.set("numLikes", this.model.get("numLikes") - 1);
            // wrapper for API
            unlikeEntity("/items/"+this.model.id); // should do something better than this to send like to server
        }
    },

    animateLike: function () {
        this.sPolyFill.animate({ transform: 't9,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
        this.sPolyEmpty.animate({ transform: 't-9,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
    },

    animateUnlike: function () {
        this.sPolyFill.animate({ transform: 't0,0'}, 300, mina.easeinout);
        this.sPolyEmpty.animate({ transform: 't0,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
    }
});

baz.View.base = Backbone.View.extend({

        // initialize variables and render template
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.render(); // render template and initializes above values
        },

        render: function () {
            return this; // A good convention is to return this at the end of render to enable chained calls.
        }
    });

baz.View.BaseButton = baz.View.base.extend({

    // backbone event hash - sets functions to events on selected buttons
    events: {
        "click button": "triggered"
    },

    // initialize variables and render template
    initialize: function (options) {
        baz.View.base.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]); // inherit from base
        this.btn = this.$("button.normal-buttons");
    },

    // fn to be called for normal and cancel buttons
    triggered: function (event) {
        this.trigger('click', this);
        this.btn.blur();
    }
});
```

My test code:

```
describe("Like Button View", function () {


    before(function () {

        this.$fixture = $('<div id="likeButton-view-fixture"></div>');

    });

    after(function () {

        $("#fixtures").empty();

    });

    describe("Like button when attribute 'LIKED' is FALSE", function () {

        beforeEach(function () {

            // set-up fake server
            this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
            this.server.autoRespond = true;

            // empty out and rebind the fixture for each run
            this.$fixture.empty().appendTo($("#fixtures"));

            this.model = new baz.Model.item({
                liked: false,
                numLikes: 0
            });

            this.view = new baz.View.likeButton ({
                el: this.$fixture,
                model: this.model
            });

            this.renderSpy = sinon.spy(this.view, "render");

            this.updateStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "_update");

            this.toggleLikeStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "toggleLike");

            this.modelChangeStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "_modelChange");

            this.likeStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "_like");

            this.unlikeStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "_unlike");

            this.animateLikeStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "animateLike");

            this.animateUnlikeStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "animateUnlike");

            this.snapAnimSpy = sinon.spy(Snap, "animate");

        });

        afterEach(function () {

            this.view.model.destroy();

            this.renderSpy.restore();

            this.updateStub.restore();

            this.toggleLikeStub.restore();

            this.modelChangeStub.restore();

            this.likeStub.restore();

            this.unlikeStub.restore();

            this.animateLikeStub.restore();

            this.animateUnlikeStub.restore();

            this.snapAnimSpy.restore();

            // undo our server
            this.server.restore();

        });

        it("call render and view should exist", function () {

            var _view = this.view.render();

            expect(_view).to.equal(this.view);
            expect(this.renderSpy).to.have.been.called;
            expect(this.view).to.be.ok;
        });

        it("should have class 'unliked'", function () {

            var _element = $(".icon")[0];

            expect(_element.className).to.include("unliked");
        });

        it("trigger 'toggleLike' when button is clicked should change liked value and call update", function () {

            var _event = $.Event("click");

            var _element = $(".icon");

            _element.trigger(_event);

            expect(this.toggleLikeStub).to.have.been.called; // this fails
            expect(this.view.model.get("liked")).to.deep.equal(true); // this fails
            expect(this.updateStub).to.have.been.called; // this fails

        });

        it("should like an item", function () {

            var _element = $(".icon")[0];

            this.view._like();

            expect(_element.className).to.include("liked");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If I manually call `_update` in my test suit, this should at least trigger `like` or `unlike` within the update function and thus at least one of my stubs should be called. But that too does not pass!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you have multiple problems here.

- `this.view._update`

  > This is happening too when I directly call `this.view._update` for example and expect my stubs `likeStub` or `unLikeStub` to be called too.

  Are you doing that after this?:

  ```js
  this.updateStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "_update");
  ```
- `toggleLikeStub`

  I think this is failing because the original `toggleLike` is being assigned as the event handler before you call `sinon.stub()`. Try doing something like this:

  ```js
  this.updateStub = sinon.stub(baz.View.likeButton.prototype, "_update");    

  this.view = new baz.View.likeButton ({
      el: this.$fixture,
      model: this.model
  });
  ```
- Where you have:

  ```js
  expect(this.updateStub).to.have.been.called; // this fails
  ```

  `updateStub()` isn't going to be called as a result of `toggleLikeStub()` being called. From the [documentation for `sinon.stub()`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs):

  > When wrapping an existing function with a stub, the original function is not called.

  Are you sure you don't want a spy?
- Misc

  I just want to make sure you're aware that instead of doing this:

  ```js
  this.toggleLikeStub = sinon.stub(this.view, "toggleLike");
  // ..
  this.toggleLikeStub.restore();
  ```

  You could just do:

  ```js
  sinon.stub(this.view, "toggleLike");
  // ..
  this.view.toggleLike.restore();
  ```

  Better yet you could do something like:

  ```js
  var meths = [
    {sinon_meth: 'stub', view_meths: ['_update', 'toggleLike', ...]},
    {sinon_meth: 'spy', view_meths: ['render', 'animate', ...]},
  ];

  meths.forEach(function (group) {
    group.view_meths.forEach(function (view_meth) {
      sinon[group.sinon_meth](view, view_meth);
    });
  });

  // ...

  meths.forEach(function (group) {
    group.view_meths.forEach(function (view_meth) {
      view[view_meth].restore();
    });
  });
  ```

  In this case I'm not sure you even need to restore them if you're doing the same setup and blowing away `this.view` before each test.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that stubbing a function prevents the original from being called. Changing to spies has sorted out most of the issues and  realising that I needed to define some of the stubs on the prototype, as you mentioned seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Great! Happy to hear it.